# Area of minimum regular polygon given three vertices

Tags: geometry, polygons, gcd-and-lcm

**Related question**: [Regular polygon determined by three vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142644/regular-polygon-determined-by-three-vertices)

I have solved a problem that is related to the linked question. It boils down to the question *"given three vertices of a regular polygon, what is the smallest possible area of a regular polygon these vertices are a part of?"*

A possible solution is to find the circumcenter and the angles it forms with each of the vertices and obtain a *lcm* (as the linked question's accepted answer describes). Another option as described by this [tutorial](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/495?#comment-203231) is to find the circumradius (*Heron's formula + area in terms of circumradius*) and the inner angles (*law of cosines*) of the triangle described by the three points, use them to find the number of sides as $\pi$ over the **greatest common denominator of the three inner angles** and use this information to calculate the area.

My question is *why does taking the quotient of $\pi$ and the `gcd` of the inner angles of the triangle give the number of sides of the polygon?* I've tested this approach and it does work but I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Given three points ${\bf z}_i$ in the plane (say,  coordinatewise) it is easy to determine the radius $r$ and center ${\bf c}$ of their circumcircle. It follows that the regular polygon of minimal area having these points as vertices **(if there exists such a polygon at all)** has area $<\pi r^2$. If the coordinates of the ${\bf z}_i$ are simple expressions containing $\sqrt{3}$, or so, you might be able to detect that they are in fact vertices of a dodecagon, but how should you be able to realize  that your ${\bf z}_i$ are in fact vertices of a regular $45\,381$-gon? It follows that your problem, fascinating as it is, is in a way ill-posed.

Comment: I think Hagen von Eitzen addressed your concerns in their answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142644/regular-polygon-determined-by-three-vertices